# How to play a sound using Qt from a specific point (timecode)?

Tags: c++, qt, audio

We have a Qt application which (among other things) plays sounds when a sound file is double-clicked.

How can we play the same sound file not from the beginning (00:00:00) but from a time value entered from elsewhere?

For example if I have a `playlist.txt` with the following line(s):

```
mysound.mp3  00:01:23
```

How can we play the `mysound.mp3` not from the beginning but from 00:01:23 (*after one minute and 23 seconds from the beginning of song*)?

Comment: how do you play the sound now?

Comment: `QMediaPlayer`has a slot called `setPosition(qint64 position)`. This is the method you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setPosition()` function of QMediaPlayer.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#position-prop